# I need to produce the answer to the following code with 2 decimal places

Tags: java

I'm very new too Java programming and in my 2nd week at university.

I have written this piece of code to sum the age of 4 people, average that number and produce a numerical result.

I have done this, but I need this piece of code to give me an answer with 2 decimal places.

The answer I get is 36 (The expected answer should be 36.75).

This is what I have so far. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int age1 = 18;
    int age2 = 35;
    int age3 = 50;
    int age4 = 44;
    double averageAge = (age1 + age2 + age3 + age4) / 4;
    System.out.println(averageAge);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted? Although it's a very basic question, it still shows effort and appears to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int/int=int`

You are dividing `int` value by `int` then result is also a `int`.

Check this

```
double averageAge = (age1 + age2 + age3 + age4) / 4.0;
```

Now you will get the correct answer. Now you are dividing `int` by a `double` and answer will be a `double`

Comment: Thankyou Ruchira, your answer was very helpful and self explanatory. I can see now where i went wrong. 

I will tick you answer when its possible (6 minutes)

Thankyou, once again!

Comment: Do you mind changing `int/int=int` to `int=int/int` so that it matches the programming rules?

Answer (score 3):

You are dividing an `integer` from an `integer`. You can cast this result into `double` by following:-

```
double averageAge = (double)(age1 + age2 + age3 + age4) / 4;
```

Comment: Thankyou Devavrata. I can see now that there is a few ways to get to the answer i was looking for.

Your answer was also very helpful, even though Ruchira provided a solution first, you have taught me that there are multiple ways to get the answer i was looking for. You have helped me alot, thankyou very much!

Answer (score 1):

You must divide by a floating point number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    int age1 = 18;
    int age2 = 35;
    int age3 = 50;
    int age4 = 44;
    double averageAge = (age1 + age2 + age3 + age4) / 4.0;
    System.out.println(averageAge);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I should not answer that question but well..

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double age1 = 18;
        double age2 = 35;
        double age3 = 50;
        double age4 = 44;
        double averageAge = (age1 + age2 + age3 + age4) / 4;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.");
        String averageAgeFormatted = df.format(averageAge);
        System.out.println(averageAgeFormatted);
    }
```

Use double for better precision but ideal solution will be if you would use BigDecimal

Comment: _Use double for better precision_: Well, the way you are using it, it won't change the final result. `age1`, `age2`, `age3`, `age4` and `4` are all integer values, so java will perform an integer division. The result will always be `36.0` (***`.0`*** because `averageAge` is a `double`).